# ORM with automatic client-server data syncronization. Are there any ready to use solutions?

Tags: orm, oop, synchronization

Consider the client application that should store its data on remote server. We do not want it to access this data "on-fly", but rather want it to have a copy of this data in local database. So we do not need connection with remote server to use application. Eventually we want to sync local database with remote server. The good example of what I am talking about is [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com) service. This type of applications is very common, for instance, in mobile development, where user is not guaranteed to have permanent Internet connection, bandwidth is limited and traffic can be expensive.

ORM (object relational mapping) solutions generally allows developer to define some intermediate "model" for his business logic data. And then work with it as some object hierarchy in his programming language, having the ability to store it relational database.

Why not to add to an ORM system a feature that will allow automatic synchronization of two databases (client and server), that share the same data model? This would simplify developing the applications of the type I described above. Is there any systems for any platform or language that have this or similar feature implemented?

Answer (score 1):

this links may provide some useful information

http://gwtsandbox.com/?q=node/34

http://www.urielkatz.com/archive/detail/google-gears-orm-v01/

http://www.urielkatz.com/archive/detail/google-gears-orm/

Comment: Hm, as far as I can see this is just for storing client-side local data. No sync with server functionality. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there are no such ORM tools.

It was one of original goals of our team (I'm one of DataObjects.Net developers), but this feature is [still not implemented](http://forum.x-tensive.com/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=5786). Likely, we'll start working on database sync this spring, but since almost nothing is done yet, there is no exact deadline for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one Open Source ORM matching your needs, but it is a Delphi ORM.

It is called [mORMot](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SQLite3+Framework), and use JSON in a stateless/RESTless architecture to communicate over GDI messages, named pipes or HTTP/1.1. It is able to connect to [any database engine](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/08/07/SQLite3-powered%2C-not-SQLite3-limited), and embed an optimized *SQlite3* engine.

It is a true *Client-Server* ORM. That is, ORM is not used only for data persistence of objects (like in other implementations), but as part of a global n-Tier, Service Oriented Architecture. *This really makes the difference*.